# crontab missing library shell script

Tags: bash, cron

getting error on a script when running from cron

```
error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do not get the error when i run it from command line.

So I do locate command on the library and found it:

```
locate  - /export/home/orahome/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
```

and add it to the end of the path in the script, but still get an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/opt/OV/bin/OpC:/usr/local/sqlite3.6.23.1/bin:/production/java/jdk32  /bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/svn/bin:  /orahome/current/bin:/production/
fo/bin:/production/fo/scr:/production/fo/tools:/export/home/orahome/11.2/lib/

/production/bin/userStats -c /production/cfg/userStats.cfg > /production/log/userStats.log 2>&1
```

but still get an error in the logs

```
casper@casperbox:> ls -ltr /production/log/userStats.log
```

-rw-r--r-- 1 casper casper  145 Oct 24 16:24 /production/log/userStats.log

```
casper@casperbox:> more /production/log/userStats.log

/production/bin/userStats: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.11.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does the library also need a lib path set? You could enter `env` to see if it appears somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not `PATH`.

Comment: that worked - how did you figure that one out - the error is not asking for that path name LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: i added this below the library path and it worked: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/export/home/orahome/11.2/lib/

Comment: `cannot open shared object file` means that some shared object (i.e. .so file) is not found in /lib64 or /usr/lib64 nor in the path defined in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It plays the same role PATH plays for executables. The `ldd` command  is very useful to find which shared objects an executable needs.